# Question on the Schrödinger interpretation on one object being split into two

Tags: mathematical-physics, quantum-mechanics

Suppose that there is an object (i.e. a wavefunction) containing $N+M$ particles, say, a person holding a mobile phone, which may or may not interact each other. Suppose also that the object needs to be split into an $N$-particle wavefunction for the person and the $M$-particle wavefunction for the phone. Intuitively the successor of the $N+M$-particle wavefunction should be the $N$-particle wavefunction, but the interacting-particle version of the Schrödinger equation does not seem to interpret it as the successor. Absorbing the $M$-particle wavefunction into the potential function does not really seem to help either.

I'm asking for a known mathematical solution (or absence of such thereafter) of this apparent paradox.

P.S. I'm a freshman in college and haven't learnt enough math to prove these sort of things myself. This is not an assignment either, as it's vacation time for most of the colleges here; while K-12 started their classes (even online ones) a month later than usual, most colleges started their lectures only two weeks later than usual.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood what you are asking, but if originally you have a wavefunction of $N+M$ particles, at the end you will also have a wavefunction (different one) of $N+M$ particles. It is just that in the limit $t\to\infty$ you can write the second wavefunction as a product of a wavefunction of $N$ particles peaked in one position and a wavefunction of $M$ particles peaked at a different location.

Comment: Are you talking about the decay of a particle to two particles, for example?